# R - Loop with If statement and tracking the number of successes

Tags: r, loops

I want to simulate different poker hands. Through painful trial and error, I got the ranks, suits, the deck and a function to draw any given number of cards as:

```
suits    <- c("spd","hrt","dimd","clbs")
ranks    <- c(1:10,"J","Q","K")
deck     <- as.matrix(expand.grid('rank' = ranks, 'suit' = suits))
draw     <- function (n) deck[sample(nrow(deck), n), ]
draw(5)                         # Drawing 5 cards from the deck...
```

Output:

```
     rank suit  
[1,] "4"  "dimd"
[2,] "6"  "dimd"
[3,] "8"  "spd" 
[4,] "K"  "hrt" 
[5,] "8"  "clbs"
```

Now I want to find out through simulation the probability of getting different hands. I did come up with some possible loops with a `counter for the number of successes` but I am stuck.

Here is an example... Let me try to figure out how many full houses I get in 1000 simulations. Since a full house is defined as "three matching cards of one rank and two matching cards of another rank", I figured that the key part of the function would be to have a boolean within an `if` statement that takes advantage of the R function `unique()==2`, meaning 2 unique ranks - with 5 cards dealt, 2 unique ranks could be a full house (another possibility is four-of-a-kind with any other rank).

```
iterations <- 1000
counter <- 0
for (i in iterations){
s <- draw(5)
if(length(unique(s[,1])) == 2) counter <- counter + 1
}
counter
```

Output: `[1] 0`

I have tried multiple other things, including `counter[i] <- 1` for successful cases, and with the idea of running a `sum(counter)` at the end, but all without getting the loop to work.

Comment: If it's homework, you should say so :)

Comment: I wish it was homework, Brandon, but I can't even remember my days in school. Just having fun, despite the unfriendly loops in R.

Comment: With 2 unique ranks you can also have a four-of-a-kind, i.e. four Kings and a Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
for(i in 1000) { 
print(i)
} # 1000
```

It would only print once because `i` would iterate once as `1000`.

Here's an alternative approach using `rle`.

```
iterations <- 10000
draws <- list()
for (i in 1:iterations){
  s <- draw(5)
  draws[[i]] <- all(rle(sort(s[,1]))$lengths %in% c(2,3))
  if(draws[[i]]) {
    print(s)
  }
}
summary(unlist(draws))
```

Comment: This is so frustrating... Now, of course, it works just fine... All it ever needed was to, instead of `for (i in iterations)`, having typed `for (i in 1: iterations)` You gave me the answer. It was so simple. You deserve the points. Can you make it explicit that this is the answer, and I will accept.

Comment: Head smacking moments abound. Happens to all of us.

Comment: With just replacing the loop syntax, you didn't fix the fact that you're also accepting four-of-a-kind. This code fixes that too.

Answer (score 1):

Using a data frame as follows, it seems to produce the result you are looking for:

```
suits    <- c("spd","hrt","dimd","clbs")
ranks    <- c(1:10,"J","Q","K")
deck     <- as.data.frame(expand.grid('rank' = ranks, 'suit' = suits))
draw     <- function (n) deck[sample(nrow(deck), n), ]

counter <- 0;
for (i in 1:1000) {
  df <- draw(5);
  counter <- counter + (length(unique(df$rank)) == 2)
}
counter
[1] 156
```

Comment: That's great, but as I was sharing with Brandon, I'm not doing homework, and I'd really like to understand what I was doing wrong, because the structure of your code and mine are rather similar...

Comment: Why is it not testing for full house?

Comment: I was testing suit. It should be rank. I will modify.

Comment: +1 Your code is neat, but it seems as though mine works just fine after fixing the problem that Brandon noticed.

Answer (score 0):

```
suits    <- c("spd","hrt","dimd","clbs")
ranks    <- c(1:10,"J","Q","K")
deck     <- as.data.frame(expand.grid('rank' = ranks, 'suit' = suits))
draw     <- function (n) deck[sample(nrow(deck), n), ]

iterations <- 1000
counter <- 0
for (i in 1:iterations) {
    hand <- draw(5)
    rank_table <- table(hand[, 1])
    if (length(names(rank_table)) == 2 & min(rank_table) > 1) counter <- counter + 1 
    # could have four of a rank, one of another;
    # need to ensure two of a rank, three of another
}
counter
[1] 1
```

This result is not far from what is expected http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ramsey/Probability/PokerHands.html